# How to solve a system of diophantine equation and gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example I want to solve this system $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
5x-3y=24 \\ 
\gcd(x,y)=8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
I found that $(x,y)=(3k+6,5k+2)$ but I think I need to find $k$ so that $\gcd(x,y)=8$

Answer (score 1):

Find $(x, y)$ such that $\gcd(x, y)=1$ and $5x-3y=3$.  For example, $x=3, y=4$.  Then multiply by $8$, yielding $x=24, y=32$.  (Note, by the way, that it wasn't guaranteed that $x, y$ non-negative would exist.)

Answer (score 1):

Let GCD(X,Y)=g and let (j,k) be the cofactors of (x,y) respectively. Then we have

$$5gj-3gk=5*8*j-3*8*k=40j-24k=24$$
$$40j=24+24k=24(1+k)$$
$$j=\frac{24(1+k)}{40}=\frac{3(1+k)}{5}$$
Now we need to find a value of k so $(1+k)=5$ so the fraction will be an integer. Let's try $k=4$.

$$j=\frac{3*(1+4)}{5}=\frac{15}{5}=3$$
By substitution of $g=8$, $j=3$, and $k=4$ we get

$$5*8*3-3*8*4=5*24-3*32=120-96=24$$